# Less than function on NVARCHAR(50) which holds numbers but in different formats

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column which has lots of different types of numbers in it, and when i preform a less than function on it it doesn't seem to work correctly.

```
0 
0.000000 
-0.001000 
0.738000 
1.000000 
10.000000 
10.005000 
10.027000 
... 
99.947000 
99.962000 
99.988000 
990.307000 
991.190000 
9918.058000 
996 
997
```

This is a sample of the numbers?

Comment: Please show the code you are using!

Comment: The biggest issue here is storing numbers as varchar. Why would you do this? You should always use the correct datatype for the data being stored.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

String comparison is not the same as numeric comparison.

If you want to compare the numbers, I would suggest converting them to either `decimal` or `float`:

```
where try_convert(float, col) < 10
```

I should, of course, mention that storing numbers in a character field is not to be recommended.  You should use the native types, if possible.

EDIT:

In pre-SQL Server 2012 versions, you should use `case`:

```
where (case when isnumeric(col) = 1 then convert(float, col)
       end) < 10
```

Comment: I assume this would probably work, but the Compatibility level is SQL Server 2005(90), sorry I forgot to mention that.